# Find selected options from multiselect of bootstrap

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

The Drop down list generating by this :-

```
@Html.DropDownList("ddlClients", null, new { @class = "pull-left", @multiple = "multiple" })
```

Converting drop down to Bootstrap's multiselect :-

```
$('#ddlClients').multiselect('destroy');
```

Comment: The DropDownList helper will not render the multiple attribute. You need to use `Html.ListBox` or `Html.ListBoxFor`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).on("change", ".classname or #ID", function () {
 var variable1= $(this).val();
});
```

or

```
$('.classname or #ID :selected').each(function (i, selected) {
    variable1 = variable1 + "," + $(selected).val();
});
```

any of the 2 variants you can use to get the value from a Multi Select